# Hibernate Restrictions API to_char() function

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Hi guys I have an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE P WHERE to_char(P.BIRTH_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') = '01/06/2012'
```

I want to run this query via Hibernate Restrictions API. I think the following won't do the same work:

```
Restrictions.eq(People.PROP_BIRTH_DATE, Calendar.getInstance())
```

How can I create such a restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2012-06-01");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(People.PROP_BIRTH_DATE, date));
```

or

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = df.parse("01/06/2012");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(People.PROP_BIRTH_DATE, date));
```

The above supposes that the birth date is stored as a date in database, and not as a timestamp. If the birth date in database is a timestamp, and thus has a time portion, the portable way of doing that is:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date begin = df.parse("01/06/2012");
Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
endCalendar.setTime(date);
endCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge(People.PROP_BIRTH_DATE, begin));
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt(People.PROP_BIRTH_DATE, endCalendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: Here the point is eliminating the time field in PROP_BIRTH_DATE field and comparing it with a date string. So i think your solution is not equivalent to the given query.

Comment: OK. You should have mentioned that the birth date was stored as a timestamp in database, because it's far from obvious. I'll edit my answer.